# Files don't open for editing on NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: 14.04, netbeans

I've installed, removed and reinstalled Netbeans 8.0.2 twice from the instructions on it's [official website](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html#install_windows).  Each time the install wizard stated that it installed correctly.  The problem is that when I try to open a file for editing I get a [blank screen](http://i62.tinypic.com/2en2afd.png) where the code should be.  (I had to link the image because I don't have enough reputation points to insert an image into this question).

My computer currently runs Ubuntu 14.04 and I have used NetBeans with previous versions of Ubuntu but this is first time I've had this problem.  Thanks for any advice.

FYI, I'm running Java SE 7 and from the command line everything works properly.  The NetBeans install wizard also detected my JDK installation each time I installed the IDE.

Comment: Have you check permissions for the sourcecode files you are trying to edit ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you. It went away by reinstalling netbeans in my `/home/username` directory.

The issue can also occur if your java version is not recent. Netbeans 8.0.2 doesnot support jdk versions 1.6 and older.